# in Spring data mongo DB, how do we get city and its level count

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My json structure is stored in Mongo DB.

```
[
   {
      "city":"Lodz",
      "level":1
   },
   {
      "city":"Warsaw",
      "level":1
   },
   {
      "city":"ssfd",
      "level":2
   },
   {
      "city":"rom",
      "level":5
   },
   {
      "city":"Lodz",
      "level":5
   },
   {
      "city":"Warsaw",
      "level":5
   },
   {
      "city":"Lodz",
      "level":1
   }
]
```

in spring data, how do we get levels count by city. for example, city "Lodz" has 2 items and Warsaw has 2 items. which is best way to get these data from Mongo DB

Comment: does the answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple way you can do.. Lets say

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Country {
  String city;
  int level;
}
```

you can write a `findAll()` query and get all documents
`List<Country> countries=countryRepository.findAll()`

then you can stream it

```
Map<String, Long> collect =
        countryList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Country::getCity, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(collect);
```

Now you have the desired output.

If you need aggregation's help, you can write a simple aggregations to get the desired output

Autowire the Mongo template

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

then

```
Aggregation aggregation =
    Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.group("city").count().as("count"))
        .withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

List<Converter> countries =
    mongoTemplate
        .aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Country.class), Converter.class)
        .getMappedResults();
```

Your Converter class might be

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Converter {
  String _id;
  Long count;
}
```